# DataGrid to PDF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, datagrid

Как вывести данные отображенные в DataGrid, в формате PDF?

Comment: первая же ссылка в гугле: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-datagridview-data-to-pdf-in-c-sharp

Comment: Ссылка не открывается. Как это сделать в Windows Forms я знаю, а вот на WPF туплю